# How to use the addChild method of javascript to add a node to my div?

Tags: php, javascript

Hello I have a div as follows

```
<div id="test" class="test2">
<p> <a href=""> <a> </p>
<p> <a href=""> <a> </p>
<p> <a href=""> <a> </p>
<p> <a href=""> <a> </p>
</div>
```

(I have stripped out the data but that is the structure)

How does one use the addChild function of javascript to add a new node

```
<p> <a href=""> <a> </p>
```

I know how to use the removeChild function but I haven't been able to find documentation and examples using the addChild function.

If I have the node string in a php array, and can execute the php script containing the array with a GET call via a button click how can I use the addChild function to put the node string into the div?

Comment: If you are getting the node string in php, why not just echo it inline?

Comment: this link might be very helpful http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml

Comment: This is definitely a PHP question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`addChild` is a php function, The javascript function is called `appendChild`:

```
var dv = document.createElement("p");
dv.innerHTML = "<a href=""> </a> ";
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(dv)
```

Alternativly, you can append the node string to the html:
`document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<p> <a href=""> <a> </p>
'`

Answer (score 1):

Since what you have is a string, you first need to create a DOM representation of it (you can't pass a string to appendChild, only a dom element). To do that the easiest way is to put it inside another element and then take its content.

```
var temp = document.createElement('div'); // create a temporary dom element
temp.innerHTML = '<p><a href="#">some cool html string</a></p>'; // give it your html string as content, the browser will then create the corresponding dom representation
var childs = temp.childNodes; // grab the resulting child elements
document.getElementById('where_to_append').appendChild(childs); // append them to where you want
```

Or you could simply set it without appendChild by using innerHTML anyway:

```
var my_div = document.getElementById('where_to_append');
my_div.innerHTML = my_div.innerHTML + '<p><a href="#">some cool html string</a></p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `append()` method to do that. Here is an example where I defined the `new_child` and added to the `parent-div`

```
var new_child = jQuery(document.createElement('p')).html("<p> <a href=""> <a></p>");

$('parent-div').append(new_child);
```

Comment: verbal explanations are helpful

Answer (score -1):

W3Schools has examples for [adding a node](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodes_add.asp) using [appendChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp)